# jquery value insertion to table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Below is my table structure how can i append data in below format

in format

```
<tr> <td>zzz</td> <td> ppp </td> </tr>

<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">

    <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>fdgfdgfg</td>
            <td>avc@example.com</td>
            <td>vbvcbvb</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly create HTML elements with jQuery:

`$("<tr><td>MyName</td><td>my@email.com</td><td>myPassword</td></tr>").appendTo("#users tbody");`

Note: in your format, you missed the third column: password

Comment: `id` is unique, if you add the selector an element type, you gain nothing except performance hit!

Comment: I didn't realise you could do thinks backwards like this... well it feels backwards to me anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<tr> <td>zzz</td> <td> ppp </td> </tr>').appendTo('#users tbody');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will add a new row to your table

```
$("#users tbody").append('<tr><td>name</td><td>email@domain.com</td><td>password</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#users tbody').append('<tr> <td>zzz</td> <td> ppp </td> </tr>');
```

As long as you have a complete html element in string , which you do, you simply append that string

http://api.jquery.com/append/